# ES6: React destructure immutable state with and without spread

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Is there a difference/advantage between

```
const { foo } = this.state
```

and with a spread

```
const { foo } = { ...this.state }
```

I'm gonna update state by calling `this.setState({foo})` at the last line.

By "difference/advantages" I mean: is there any mutations (like `push`) on `foo` that can ONLY be done properly by the destruction of a spreaded state (the latter )?

Comment: there is a difference, but there's no way to say if it is advantageous unless you provide a reason why you're doing this. the difference is that in the first codeblock you modify `foo` you also modify `this.state.foo`. in the second block you won't since you're shallow copying the keys to another object. you shouldn't ever be mutating state anyways so...

Comment: So the latter is advantageous because I can securely perform mutations and then update state by `this.setState({foo})`

Comment: don't do that though. just don't make mutations

Answer (score 1):

Well if something works in a version that needs "less work" from the cpu.

Second version:

- you are breaking the original object
- creating a new object
- and then copying the value

First version you are using the original object to copy from, so you are just doing step three from the second version

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a subtle difference beyond the fact that the spread creates a new object. Spread also only copies the objects own enumerable properties.

Consider:

```js
let proto_state = {foo: "mark"}
let state = Object.create(proto_state)
console.log(state.foo) // inherits it from the proto_state

let {foo} = {...state} // undefined not own prop
console.log(foo);

({foo} = state)  // gets the inherited foo
console.log(foo);
```

I have no idea if this will actually be an issues with your code, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is in that in second case you first clone the state and then destructure it. It adds one more unneeded step since you should have cloning/immutable update on the write side to the state.